# loop function not creating plots in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to generate 7 ggplot plots automatically in R and trying to save as png in a directory. I am using the following code but it is not saving anything. When I run the parts inside the loop separately after defining an i, it saves a plot but when I define the function as a whole and call the function, it does nothing. Any help on this issue would be of great help!

```
bar <- function() {
  library(ggplot2)
  for (i in 1:10) {
    print(i)
    days <- c("SAT","SUN","MON","TUE", "WED","THUR", "FRI")
    revenue <- rnorm(7, 2000, 300) 
    d <- data.frame(
      days = factor(c("SAT","SUN","MON","TUE", "WED","THUR", "FRI"),levels= c("SAT","SUN","MON","TUE", "WED","THUR", "FRI")),
      revenue)
    mypath <- file.path("~", "Documents", "FirstData", "Rcodes","SAVEHERE",paste("myplot_",i,".png", sep = ""))
    print(mypath)
    png(file = mypath)
      ggplot(data = d, aes(x = as.factor(days), y= revenue)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="blue")
    dev.off()

  }
}

bar()
```

This piece of code was motivated from [automatically save your plots to a folder](http://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/)

Comment: I'm not an expert on `ggplot2`, but try removing `png()`, `dev.off()` and replacing with `ggsave(mypath)` after the `ggplot` call. Also, you can take the library load out of the funtion.

Comment: Check this: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Output_to_a_file/

Comment: Just add an explicit `print()` around the `ggplot()`, ie `print(ggplot(...))`